# Jade: How to automatically render the .jade filepath in html comments

Tags: html, pug

Is there a way to render the filepath of the original .jade file into the resulting .html file as a html comment **automatically**?

Example:

```
<!-- file: ../src/partials/navigation.jade -->
<div id="navigation">...</div>
```

Comment: how are you using jade? show a code snippet how you call the jade render function

Comment: i'm using [gulp-jade](https://github.com/phated/gulp-jade) ...